# Close button on modal not working...what am i doing wrong?

Tags: html, twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3, modal-dialog

I've made a modal that makes an image pop up when it's clicked but I can't get the close button to work for some reason. Can someone check my code and see where I went wrong? Or give me some suggestions...thank you!

```
<div id = "myModal" class = "modal">
        <div class = "modal-content">
            <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-hidden="true">&times;</button>
            <!-- Modal Content (The Image) -->
            <img class="modal-content" id="mimg">

            <!-- Modal Caption (Image Text) -->
            <div id="caption"></div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <img id="myImg" src="http://i0.kym-cdn.com/photos/images/newsfeed/001/023/007/f29.png" alt="Trolltunga, Norway" width="300" height="200">
```

Comment: Is this bootstrap (3)? Please add the tag.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Simple example, if you use bootstrap, make sure to do it the bootstrap way.

Also, make sure the references are correct.

```
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
```

```css
#myImg {
  width: 100%;
  height: auto;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>

<button type="button" class="btn" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#myModal">Open Modal</button>

<div id="myModal" class="modal">
  <div class="modal-dialog">
    <div class="modal-content">
      <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-hidden="true">&times;</button>
      <!-- Modal Content (The Image) -->
      <img id="myImg" src="https://pbs.twimg.com/media/BU27_rrCYAAckFP.jpg" alt="Trolltunga, Norway">
      <!-- Modal Caption (Image Text) -->
      <div id="caption">Modal Caption (Image Text)</div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: trying it now broski

Comment: I finally got it working thank you so much!! turns out it was something in my CSS...I'm figuring it out now...bless you

Answer (score 0):

**Your Code is not complete. Try to add like below**

```html
<!-- Trigger the modal with a button -->
<button type="button" class="btn btn-info btn-lg" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#myModal">Open Modal</button>

<!-- Modal -->
<div id="myModal" class="modal fade" role="dialog">
  <div class="modal-dialog">

    <!-- Modal content-->
    <div class="modal-content">
      <div class="modal-header">
        <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal">&times;</button>
        <h4 class="modal-title">Modal Header</h4>
      </div>
      <div class="modal-body">
        <p>Some text in the modal.</p>
      </div>
      <div class="modal-footer">
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
      </div>
    </div>

  </div>
</div>
Try it Yourself »
```

Comment: are you use bootstrap.js ? open your inspact and see what are showing in console tab

Comment: it's just not liking the images I've used other then that nothing

Comment: jquery.min.js:3 Mixed Content: The page at 'https://preview.c9users.io/cstephens1911/theartisanemporium/blackpropix.html?_c9_id=livepreview1&_c9_host=https://ide.c9.io' was loaded over HTTPS, but requested an insecure image 'http://i.dailymail.co.uk/i/pix/2017/03/13/13/3E39C90700000578-4308866-image-m-5_1489410821924.jpg'. This content should also be served over HTTPS.

Comment: @Breevie your image are hosted by a site without HTTPS, it is HTTP which is not safe usually. Try this link `https://pbs.twimg.com/media/BU27_rrCYAAckFP.jpg`